# How to install a platform dictionary in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, dictionary, spell-checking

For spell checking purpose I would like to install an addictional "platform dictionary" in my Eclipse IDE.

You can see the list of platform dictionaries installed in Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Spelling, in the field "Platform dictionary". In my Helios Service Release 1 there are only english of UK or USA. I would to put the language of my country, so I can write comments in my language and have spell check. Eclipse help doesn't explain how.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I am not sure you can add a "Platform dictionary", so that leaves you with a "user defined" one:

[image]

Eclipse supports a standard one-word-per-line format for the 'dictionary' file.
You can have several of those at **[Kevin's Word List on Sourceforge.net](http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/)**, including links to other sites.

Comment: Even if it seems a strange design choice in Eclipse, it works! Thanks!
To find the wordlist for my language I found usefull searching the internet for "<language> wordlist".

Answer (score 24):

If you can't find your language word list you can generate one using aspell.

```
aspell --lang=pl dump master | aspell --lang=pl expand | tr ' ' '\n' > pl.dict
```

In Ubuntu aspell generates list in UTF-8 in other systems you can add encoding option.

```
--encoding=utf-8
```

Comment: it slows down eclipse too much. my cpu stays running at 100% and eclipse freezes with any open text-file

Comment: Easy way to get a large word list. You have to install the Aspell language package first.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't find a good worldlist and can't run aspell, you can also get wordlists from Debian. On Windows, I used the [Swiss German wordlist](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/wswiss). Klick **all**, pick a mirror, download the .deb file, use 7-zip or similar to open it, open the data.tar inside, and find the file you are looking for. In my case it was `/usr/share/dict/swiss`.

Comment: Found a dead Link :(

Comment: I changed that Ubuntu link to a Debian Jessie link.

Comment: Cool that helped.
Just provide this link because not everybody is interested in German.
Extracted the file to my .p2 folder and restarted Eclipse and it worked.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @VonC, @Konrad Nowicki and @Alex Schröder for the earlier answers. I didn't find the other answers fully satisfying so I wanted to write my own answer. Your question:

**How to install a platform dictionary in Eclipse?**

**For English:**

Since you mentioned that US and UK English is included, no need to explain.

**For non-English languages, like languages with strange characters like åäöü, example here is Swedish (tested and it works):**

Download a text file of the words. My method for downloading a file of words: I googled `swedish word list txt` (just change `swedish` to whatever language you're looking for a dictionary and I hope you'll find a `txt` dictionary) and found this (this link worked 2018-09-25) GitHub repo with an Swedish dictionary: https://github.com/martinlindhe/wordlist_swedish. As long as your dictionary file is formatted correctly in `UTF-8` and have EOL (End of lines) characters `Unix (LF)` it should be fine. However, if it isn't formatted as `UTF-8` you'll have to convert the åäöü characters to reflect the `UTF-8` standard, example program for this: `Notepad++`. If the dictionary has another EOL characters: `Windows (CR LF)` or `Macintosh (CR)`, then just convert it to `Unix (LF)`, example program for this: `Notepad++`. Then open a text editor, example program for this: `Notepad++`, to append the new dictionary to your custom dictionary where it is located, often times `%userprofile%/eclipse/dictionary.txt` or `~/eclipse/dictionary.txt` depending on where you installed `Eclipse`. Restart `Eclipse` and it should work.